# How can i check in numpy if a binary image is almost all black?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy, scikit-image

How can i see in if a binary image is almost all black or all white in numpy or scikit-image modules ?

I thought about `numpy.all` function or `numpy.any` but i do not know how neither for a total black image nor for a almost black image.

Comment: Well, first you'd have to define "almost all black". I can instantly come up with at least two different useful definitions, and examples where they lead to different judgements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all the pixels really are ones or zeros, something like this might work (not at all tested):

```
def is_sorta_black(arr, threshold=0.8):
    tot = np.float(np.sum(arr))
    if tot/arr.size  > (1-threshold):
       print "is not black" 
       return False
    else:
       print "is kinda black"
       return True
```

Comment: Why not use `arr.mean()` instead of `np.float(np.sum(arr))/arr.size)`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of ideas I can think of:

1. get the `np.sum()` and if it is lower than a threshold, then consider it almost black
2. calculate `np.mean()` and `np.std()` of the image, an almost black image is an image that has low mean and low variance

Comment: I vote 2. `whiteness = image.mean(); blackness = 1 - whiteness`